# Spring Integration Aggregator

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I want to use an aggregator to create a message out of two messages, but i'm not sure how to do this.

At the moment i'm reading in two files from a directory and want to aggregate those messages into one.

My whole project looks like this:

read in .zip -> pass to custom message handler that unzips it into a directory -> read files from this directory -> try to aggregate them

It would be great if i could send a message with two payloads after unzipping the file, but aggregating after reading it would suffice.

My unzipper looks like this:

```
public class ZipHandler extends AbstractMessageHandler {

File dat;
File json;

@Override
protected void handleMessageInternal(Message<?> message) throws Exception {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    try {
        File file = (File) message.getPayload();
        ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(file);

        for (Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = zip.entries(); entries
                .hasMoreElements();) {
            ZipEntry ze = entries.nextElement();
            String name = ze.getName();

            if (name.endsWith(".dat") || name.endsWith(".DAT")) {
                InputStream input = zip.getInputStream(ze);
                File datFile = new File("D:/lrtrans/zipOut"
                        + File.separator + name);
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(datFile);
                int len;
                while ((len = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
                }
                this.dat = datFile;
                fos.close();
            } else if (name.endsWith(".json") || name.endsWith(".JSON")) {
                InputStream input = zip.getInputStream(ze);
                File jsonFile = new File("D:/lrtrans/zipOut"
                        + File.separator + name);
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(jsonFile);
                int len;
                while ((len = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
                }
                this.json = jsonFile;
                fos.close();
            }
        }
        zip.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

It takes those files and puts them into two directories, from which i read them in again using FileReadingMessageSource. 
I also would like to solve this using only annotation based notation, not xml.

**Edit:**

I want to just use the defaultAggregatingMessagegroupProcssor with the correlationStrategy based on my header called "zip" and a releaseStrategy based on the message since, in this case two files should be combined into one.

```
@Aggregator(inputChannel = "toAggregatorChannel", outputChannel = "toRouterChannel", discardChannel = "nullChannel")
public DefaultAggregatingMessageGroupProcessor aggregate(){
    DefaultAggregatingMessageGroupProcessor aggregator = new DefaultAggregatingMessageGroupProcessor(); 
    return aggregator;
}
@CorrelationStrategy 
public String correlateBy(@Header("zipFile") String zip){
    return zip;
}
@ReleaseStrategy
public boolean isReadytoRelease(List<Message<?>> messages) {
    return messages.size() == 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say that you go right way. Since you zip has several files in it, it is correct requirement to unzip it and collect those files as one message and send for the further process.

So, yes, `<aggregator>` is for you. There is just need to determine how to correlate and group them.

Don't know how you unzip them, but you really can use zip file name as a `correlationKey` and use a number of files for group size to determine a signal to release the group.

Feel free to ask more questions. But first of all I need to see your "unzipper".

**UPDATE**

First of all, annotation-based aggregator configuration is a bit limited and it is better to use `@ServiceActivator` on the `AggregatingMessageHandler` `@Bean` to have more control over its options.

However, you can achieve your requirements even with that your choice. But `@Aggregator` configuration should follow with POJO-method invocation principles:

```
@Aggregator(inputChannel = "toAggregatorChannel", outputChannel = "toRouterChannel", discardChannel = "nullChannel")
public List<File> aggregate(List<File> files){
    return files;
}
```

Something like that.

Comment: I found out how to create a header for my correlation strategy, but i'm not sure how to use the standard DefaultAggregatingMessageGroupProcessor. I thought to just return it and use the @Aggregator Annotation defining in and output channels but this does seem to just create a new message with the DefaultAggregatingMessageGroupProcessor as payload and discard the old two files. I'll edit this code into the question